# Test Database and Codeception

Tags: laravel, phpunit, codeception

I'm working With Laravel 5 / Codeception.

I'm working with a test database.

Here is my config:

acceptance.suite.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
enabled:
    - WebDriver
    - \Helper\Acceptance
    - Db
    - Asserts

config:
    WebDriver:
        url: 'http://laravel.dev'
        browser: 'phantomjs'
        window_size: 1024x768
    Db:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=laravel.dev;dbname=kendo_test'
        user: 'homestead'
        password: 'secret'
```

So, here I define my db being my Test db.

Then, in my bootstrap.php I have:

```
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
```

And .env.testing:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=kendo_test
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

As a test, I changed kendo_test to kendo_test2, and it failed, it is using this db.

Now, When I execute an acceptance test, my test fails because row is inserted in main db, not test, And I don't know why....

Here is my test:

```
public function it_create_user(\AcceptanceTester $I, $scenario)
{
    App::setLocale('en');
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();

    $I = new SimpleUser($scenario);
    $I->logAsUser();
    $I->dontSee(trans_choice('core.user', 2) . ' </a></li>');
    $I->logout();
    $I = new SuperAdmin($scenario);
    $I->logAsSuperAdmin();

    $I->click('#dropdown-user');
    $I->click(trans_choice('core.user', 2));
    $I->click(trans('core.addModel', ['currentModelName' => trans_choice('core.user', 1)]));
    $I->fillField('name',$user->name );
    $I->fillField('email',$user->email);
    $I->fillField('firstname',$user->firstname);
    $I->fillField('lastname',$user->lastname);
    $I->fillField('password','111111');
    $I->fillField('password_confirmation','111111');
    $I->click(trans('core.save')); // <-- Here is should save it
    $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/users');
    $I->seeInSource(trans('msg.user_create_successful'));
    $I->seeInDatabase('ken_users', ['name' => $user->name]);
}
```

Any Idea why???

Comment: When you click `$I->click(trans('core.save'));` it will be used the `.env` from your app and not the one from `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom`.

Comment: No. It should load .env.testing called in bootstrap.php

Answer (score 1):

When you click `$I->click(trans('core.save'));` it will be used the .env from your app and not the one from `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom`.

This is because when running acceptance tests you are interacting with your app via a browser.

The test being run has its own instance, as well as the app accessed by the test.

The only reason here you would use `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom` is to leverage Eloquent, and even then it must be on a separate connection.